# MySQL and Python shells don't insert the letter 'b'

Tags: linux, shell, python, mysql, prompt

It's weird, but I can't insert the letter 'b' into the MySQL and Python shells. My keyboard works perfect and the 'B' key is being inserted (shift+b). It also works into Zsh, Vim, etc...

I'm using GNU/Linux Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I tried it from Konsole, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal and URxvt to be sure it's not a terminal issue. I tried it out of tmux as well to be sure it's not caused by the multiplexer. I tried it using Zsh and bash to be sure it's not shell-related.

I found "related" answers talking about the files `.pythonrc` and `.pythonstartup`. I don't have these files, so I created them trying to use the exposed solutions for the Python case and none of them worked.

BTW, is the MySQL prompt using the Python libraries?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I fixed it removing the following line from the file `~/.inputrc`:

`bindkey -v`

Comment: Is the problem persistent i.e. does it still happen when you reboot your machine ? If you mean the `mysql client` when you write `the MySQL prompt`, then it is not related to Python.

Comment: Yes, it happens after rebooting my machine. It's really weird because it happens into MySQL and into Python when they are not related. It's like a bug propagated in several cli-tools.

Comment: Seems strange - do both of those use readline?  If so, look to see if you have an `~/.inputrc`, and try renaming that to see if that's your problem.

Comment: Yes, I think they use readline because I can move around characters using ctrl-a, ctrl-e, ctrl-f, ctrl-b, ctrl-u, ctrl-w... However, I don't have the file `.inputrc`. I can create it and try it with some settings.

Comment: Fixed! My fault. Didn't see that I had `~/.inputrc`, even under control version in my dotfiles, LOL. The content of this file was `bindkey -v`, so I removed this line.